# How to move Scene's .commands clause into its own function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm learning SwiftUI, so I apologize if I'm asking the obvious.

Say, if I have the following code snippet:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene
    {
        WindowGroup
        {
            ContentView()
            .onAppear
            {
                //Code that runs when app is shown
            }
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .appInfo) {
                //code here...
            }
            CommandGroup(replacing: .appTermination) {
                //code here...
            }
            CommandGroup(before: .saveItem) {
                //code here
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

How do I move the `.commands` clause into their own function?

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem correct:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene
    {
        WindowGroup
        {
            ContentView()
            .onAppear
            {
                //Code that runs when app is shown
            }
        }
        .commands {
             onSetMainMenu()
        }
    }

    func onSetMainMenu()
    {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .appInfo) {
            //code here...
        }
        CommandGroup(replacing: .appTermination) {
            //code here...
        }
        CommandGroup(before: .saveItem) {
            //code here
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me an error that I don't understand:

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'Commands'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like the [`@ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) commonly used for splitting out functions that build part of a view hierarchy, there is a [`@CommandsBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/commandsbuilder) annotation as well:

```
@CommandsBuilder
func onSetMainMenu() -> some Commands {
    CommandGroup(replacing: .appInfo) {
        //code here...
    }
    CommandGroup(replacing: .appTermination) {
        //code here...
    }
    CommandGroup(before: .saveItem) {
        //code here
    }
}
```